# Javascript debugger for PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Though PhoneGap is very quick way of making applications, debugging becomes difficult.
Is there any good debugging/testing tool for javascript written for PhoneGap such as IE developer tools?

Thank you.

Comment: This might help you: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494768/Debugging%20PhoneGap%20Apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to go for mobile debugging to get as good as desktop, but [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) and [ripple](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/) come the closest that I've seen.

Weinre does web inspection to a remote device (no breakpoints). Ripple is a Chrome plug-in that uses simulation to run and debug mobile apps in the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Today there are some new tools.

Right now I am debugging a cordova application programmed for android.

My suggestion is to use GapDebug for Debugging. This is a real debugger where you have:

- a full JavaScript Debugger (setting breakpoints works great)
- CSS and DOM inspector as good as in "chrome developer tools"
- in GapDebug GUI you can deploy your .apk files directly to the smartphone
- the process between the cmd-command "cordova build" and the "starting of the app on the smartphone" is even quicker than starting it in the cordova-emulator

Have fun:
https://www.genuitec.com/intro_gapdebug/